# Change Facebook's Shared URL Meta Information Via PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, share, meta

I'm setting up a couple of websites as an extension of a primary URL, and want Facebook to recognise that each subdomain or subfolder is a unique entity.

So I have: `http://business.com` and on that I have `http://business.com/website-1`, however some will be `http://website-2.business.com`.

Either way, when I share a url link on facebook I'm shown the default `Picture/Title/Description + Url | Author`, and it's the last part which is a problem.

I produce the `Author` name by coding `<meta name="author" content="My Name">` into my `<head>` section.

The problem is that every article I share on facebook produces:

`Business.com | My Name`.

How can I set some code for it to display:

`Website 1 | My Name` ... `Website 2 | My Name` ... `etc`?

Comment: Should be `og:site_name`

Comment: I just tried that @CBroe, but unfortunately it doesn't work???

Comment: you can't do thaton fb. it uses the root domain

Comment: @volumeone - Using a subdomain it will show wesbite-1.busines.com, which is lightly better, but can't you just show the subdomain? I've seen a few posts which show something completely different to the actual domain, how can that be done?

Comment: Did you refresh the FB cache? (And research that please before asking how.)

Comment: I've just run the Debugger and added a url, and get no information about the `site_name`. Am I correct when I use it like... `<meta property="og:site_name" content="<?php echo $name; ?>" />`?